# Backup SMS and MMS to Google One on G Suite or Google Workspace account

Tags: sms, google-account, mms, google-backup, google-one

I'm a G Suite/Google Workspace user. I have 22977 messages including media (MMS & RCS), but it can't backup to Google. In Android backup, it only shows 1.0 MB for backed-up SMS and MMS.

[image]

How to fix it?